# Negative Lookahead RegEx

Tags: regex, perl

Why is this not working? Trying to do a negative lookahead. I am trying to pull the numbers from the bins, except in quarantine bin and inspection bin. When I do the code with the ^ in the front is matches all numbers in parenthesis.  When I remove the ^ it matches nothing.

Also can you use the "or operator |" inside the negative lookahead? I want to have ^(?!Quarantine_Bin|Inspection_Bin)

I also tried to specifically negate `[^Quarantine_Bin]` and it is still matching.

```
^(?!Quarantine_Bin)\([0-9]+\)
```

Data

```
    Quarantine(2),Other_Bin(2),Quarantine_Bin(2),Quarantine_Bin(2),
    Quarantine_Bin(5),Inspection_Bin(3),Regular_Bin(5),other(2)
```

Comment: So, only `2` and `5` should get extracted from the string above? https://regex101.com/r/UAlyEG/1?

Comment: But honestly - I'd suggest _don't_ regex like this, and instead `split /,/` and match the values as separate tests. Complex regex aren't good for program maintenance.

Comment: @Sobrique each line can have different number of bins so would you think that split is the best route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using a negative lookbehind as:

```
(?<!\b(Quarantine|Inspection)_Bin)\([0-9]+\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NL4PBz/2)

`(?<!\b(Quarantine|Inspection)_Bin)` is a negative lookbehind that asserts failure if there is `Quarantine_Bin` or `Inspection_Bin` before our match.
`\b` is for word boundary.

Answer (score 5):

It's a negative *lookbehind*

```
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @strings = (
    "Quarantine_Bin(5),Inspection_Bin(3),Regular_Bin(5),other(2)",
    "Quarantine(2),Other_Bin(2),Quarantine_Bin(2),Quarantine_Bin(2),"
);

for (@strings) {
    my @m = $_ =~ /(?<!\b(?:Quarantine|Inspection)_Bin)\(\d+\)/g; 
    say "@m";
}
```

The `^` anchor doesn't do what you want here, use `\b` to specify a word boundary.

This includes the parenthesis with numbers, returning lines `(5) (2)` and `(2) (2)`.

If you'd rather omit them, add capturing parethesis around numbers

```
/(?<! \b(?: Quarantine|Inspection)_Bin ) \( (\d+) \)/xg;
```

or pull the opening paren inside the lookbehind (so it is not consumed) and leave out the closing one

```
/(?<! \b(?: Quarantine|Inspection)_Bin \( ) \d+/xg;
```

These return lines `5 2` and `2 2`, no parens.

The `/x` modifier allows spaces inside for readability.

Answer (score 2):

`^(?!Quarantine_Bin)\([0-9]+\)` checks if the start of the string isn't followed by `Quarantine_Bin` but is followed by `\([0-9]\)`. That can never be true.

`[^Quarantine_Bin]` matches a single character that isn't `B`, `Q`, `a`, `e`, `i`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `u` or `_`. Not what you want.

---

Without the filtering, you'd have

```
\b\w+\([0-9]+\)
```

You want to ensure the `\b` isn't followed by `Quarantine_Bin` or `Inspection_Bin`, so you can use

```
\b(?!Quarantine_Bin\b)(?!Inspection_Bin\b)\w+\([0-9]+\)
```

or

```
\b(?!(?:Quarantine|Inspection)_Bin\b)\w+\([0-9]+\)
```

The `\b` within the lookahead prevents `Quarantine_Bin_X` from being filtered out.

---

Useful:

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the comment, so I'll flesh it out as an actual answer.

I would suggest generally avoiding lookahead/behind regexes, because it can get complicated and messy. In your use case - I'd probably just `split` the line into an array, and handle each individually.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp;
    #split on comma;
    #grep out Inspection_Bin and Quarantine_Bin
    my @fields = grep { not m/(?:Quarantine|Inspection)_Bin/ } split /,/;
    #iterate each field, and select out two different regex matches, e.g.
    #word bit and number bit. 
    print m/^(\w+)/, "=>", m/\((\d+)\)/, "\n" for @fields;
}


__DATA__
Quarantine(2),Other_Bin(2),Quarantine_Bin(2),Quarantine_Bin(2),Quarantine_Bin(5),Inspection_Bin(3),Regular_Bin(5),other(2)
```