# Pyspark path regex negative lookahead

Tags: regex, pyspark, parquet, regex-lookarounds

I have parquet dirs named like so:

```py
parquetNames = [NAME1,NAME1_MS,NAME2, NAME2_MQ]
```

I want to load only the parquets in `NAME1` and `NAME2`, but I'm having trouble with the negative lookahead and alternation. If I do:

```py
s3BaseDir+'NAME*'
```

then as expected all parquet dirs are loaded. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493294/negative-lookahead-regex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782763/how-to-use-regex-to-include-exclude-some-input-files-in-sc-textfile) I could do a negative lookahead with alternation like so to avoid either full substrings `"_MS"` or `"_MQ"`:

```py
s3BaseDir+'NAME*(?!{_MS,_MQ})'
```

But I'm getting

`AnalysisException: 'Path does not exist'`.

It seems its taking the more complex regex literally.

Are negative lookaheads doable in pyspark `spark.read.parquet`? Is it possible to combine it with alternation too? How?

Comment: Could you not just use `re` or do you have to use `spark.read.parquet`?

Comment: I thought about retrieving all the parquet names and filtering out using standard `re` but that involves I think third libraries that I don't want/cannot use.

Comment: `re` is not third-party and usually does not involve third party libraries, if you use it correctly.

Comment: Fair enough. I meant to say that I'd like to avoid fetching all the parquet file names using for example boto3, regexing, and then reading the desired parquets only. I'd like to use spark directly to filter out at load time but it seems that regex has a very limited functionality at the moment in `spark.parquet.read`.